# GoogleVis not working in R: Motion chart not loading in the browser. Getting blank browser

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

I'm having issues getting GoogleVis to work.  When I plot using GoogleVis, I get a blank browser.  Here's what I did:

1. I used the built-in R dataset, 'ChickWeight'
2. Installed RJSONIO and googleVis packages.
3. For simplicity, I truncated the ChickWeight dataframe to 24 rows: ChickWeight1<-ChickWeight[1:24,]
4. Then called the gvisMotionChart function, assigning it an object: 
   visualization1<-gvisMotionChart(ChickWeight1,idvar='weight',timevar='Time')
5. Running the above code gave me a warning message.  Not sure if warning message is related:

Warning message:
In if (class(x[[.x]]) == "Date") as.character(x[[.x]]) else x[[.x]] :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

1. I then plotted the object: plot(visualization1)

I expected a motion chart, but I just got a blank browser.  I also tried converting the 'Time' column from a numeric to date class, but no luck.

I'm using R 3.0.2, Mac OS X version 10.6.8 and Safari Version 5.1.2 (6534.52.7).  I also ran the the same code on my work Windows laptop, but no luck.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full error that you got after typing:

`mchart1<-gvisMotionChart(ChickWeight1,idvar='weight',timevar='Time')`  was:

`Error in gvisCheckMotionChartData(data, my.options) : 
  The data must have rows with unique combinations of idvar and timevar.
Your data has 578 rows, but idvar and timevar only define 375 unique rows.
In addition: Warning message:
In if (class(x[[.x]]) == "Date") as.character(x[[.x]]) else x[[.x]] :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

This error would have clued you in to the fact that you hadn't designated the ids of the chicks. If you do `mchart1<-gvisMotionChart(ChickWeight,idvar='Chick',timevar='Time')` This will give you the motion plot of how the chicks gain weight over time.

`?gvisMotionChart` is very useful.